# Is it possible to burrow units to avoid damage from Psionic Storm?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

If there was a Psionic Storm placed down over Zerg units, could you burrow them to avoid damage? If not, do they have any kind of reduced damage for being underground?

Comment: Related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18961/splash-damage-to-burrowed-units-in-starcraft2

Comment: Yeah, that is similar but its not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Burrowed zerg units take full damage from all sources, as burrowing only hides the unit from sight.

This includes damage from AoE abilities, like Psionic Storm or enemy Infestors' fungal growth, which don't require a target (though you probably don't want to waste energy unless you're sure something is hidden there).

Comment: Burrowed and cloaked units are visible to the player on the map. If you are looking carefully, they are easy to spot. Storms and Fungals are a pretty usual response. EMPs also reveal cloaked units temporarily, by the way.

Comment: Burrowed units also take damage from splash damage. (Was used a lot in BW to kill lurkers)